# Sidr is not working when I uploaded my website online

Tags: jquery, sidr

While I'm coding it on my laptop and checking the preview in browsers, Sidr is working fine. When I was done with the whole website and uploaded it in my hosting account, I found out that Sidr isn't working anymore. Here is my HTML and the JS file.

```js
/*! Sidr - v1.2.1 - 2013-11-06
 * https://github.com/artberri/sidr
 * Copyright (c) 2013 Alberto Varela; Licensed MIT */
(function(e){var t=!1,i=!1,n={isUrl:function(e){var t=RegExp("^(https?:\\/\\/)?((([a-z\\d]([a-z\\d-]*[a-z\\d])*)\\.)+[a-z]{2,}|((\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}))(\\:\\d+)?(\\/[-a-z\\d%_.~+]*)*(\\?[;&a-z\\d%_.~+=-]*)?(\\#[-a-z\\d_]*)?$","i");return t.test(e)?!0:!1},loadContent:function(e,t){e.html(t)},addPrefix:function(e){var t=e.attr("id"),i=e.attr("class");"string"==typeof t&&""!==t&&e.attr("id",t.replace(/([A-Za-z0-9_.\-]+)/g,"sidr-id-$1")),"string"==typeof i&&""!==i&&"sidr-inner"!==i&&e.attr("class",i.replace(/([A-Za-z0-9_.\-]+)/g,"sidr-class-$1")),e.removeAttr("style")},execute:function(n,s,a){"function"==typeof s?(a=s,s="sidr"):s||(s="sidr");var r,d,l,c=e("#"+s),u=e(c.data("body")),f=e("html"),p=c.outerWidth(!0),g=c.data("speed"),h=c.data("side"),m=c.data("displace"),v=c.data("onOpen"),y=c.data("onClose"),x="sidr"===s?"sidr-open":"sidr-open "+s+"-open";if("open"===n||"toggle"===n&&!c.is(":visible")){if(c.is(":visible")||t)return;if(i!==!1)return o.close(i,function(){o.open(s)}),void 0;t=!0,"left"===h?(r={left:p+"px"},d={left:"0px"}):(r={right:p+"px"},d={right:"0px"}),u.is("body")&&(l=f.scrollTop(),f.css("overflow-x","hidden").scrollTop(l)),m?u.addClass("sidr-animating").css({width:u.width(),position:"absolute"}).animate(r,g,function(){e(this).addClass(x)}):setTimeout(function(){e(this).addClass(x)},g),c.css("display","block").animate(d,g,function(){t=!1,i=s,"function"==typeof a&&a(s),u.removeClass("sidr-animating")}),v()}else{if(!c.is(":visible")||t)return;t=!0,"left"===h?(r={left:0},d={left:"-"+p+"px"}):(r={right:0},d={right:"-"+p+"px"}),u.is("body")&&(l=f.scrollTop(),f.removeAttr("style").scrollTop(l)),u.addClass("sidr-animating").animate(r,g).removeClass(x),c.animate(d,g,function(){c.removeAttr("style").hide(),u.removeAttr("style"),e("html").removeAttr("style"),t=!1,i=!1,"function"==typeof a&&a(s),u.removeClass("sidr-animating")}),y()}}},o={open:function(e,t){n.execute("open",e,t)},close:function(e,t){n.execute("close",e,t)},toggle:function(e,t){n.execute("toggle",e,t)},toogle:function(e,t){n.execute("toggle",e,t)}};e.sidr=function(t){return o[t]?o[t].apply(this,Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1)):"function"!=typeof t&&"string"!=typeof t&&t?(e.error("Method "+t+" does not exist on jQuery.sidr"),void 0):o.toggle.apply(this,arguments)},e.fn.sidr=function(t){var i=e.extend({name:"sidr",speed:200,side:"left",source:null,renaming:!0,body:"body",displace:!0,onOpen:function(){},onClose:function(){}},t),s=i.name,a=e("#"+s);if(0===a.length&&(a=e("<div />").attr("id",s).appendTo(e("body"))),a.addClass("sidr").addClass(i.side).data({speed:i.speed,side:i.side,body:i.body,displace:i.displace,onOpen:i.onOpen,onClose:i.onClose}),"function"==typeof i.source){var r=i.source(s);n.loadContent(a,r)}else if("string"==typeof i.source&&n.isUrl(i.source))e.get(i.source,function(e){n.loadContent(a,e)});else if("string"==typeof i.source){var d="",l=i.source.split(",");if(e.each(l,function(t,i){d+='<div class="sidr-inner">'+e(i).html()+"</div>"}),i.renaming){var c=e("<div />").html(d);c.find("*").each(function(t,i){var o=e(i);n.addPrefix(o)}),d=c.html()}n.loadContent(a,d)}else null!==i.source&&e.error("Invalid Sidr Source");return this.each(function(){var t=e(this),i=t.data("sidr");i||(t.data("sidr",s),"ontouchstart"in document.documentElement?(t.bind("touchstart",function(e){e.originalEvent.touches[0],this.touched=e.timeStamp}),t.bind("touchend",function(e){var t=Math.abs(e.timeStamp-this.touched);200>t&&(e.preventDefault(),o.toggle(s))})):t.click(function(e){e.preventDefault(),o.toggle(s)}))})}})(jQuery);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>Elvinia Lacson</title>
        <link rel="icon" 
        type="image/png" 
        href="images/icon.png">
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.sidr.dark.css">
  <script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="js/jquery.sidr.min.js"></script>
        <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#simple-menu').sidr();
  });
  </script>
                
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
 $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
})
</script>
  
</head>

<body>
    <div class="loader"></div>
  
    <div id="menubox"><a id="simple-menu" href="#sidr"><img src="images/menu.png"></a></div>
  <div id="sidr">
     <ul>
       <img src="images/logo b.png">
       <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
       <li class="active"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="reel.html">Reel</a></li>
       <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
     </ul>
            </p>
  </div>
 


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would verify is the external files (CSS, JS) are loaded properly or not. Please use inspect element on your live site.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a couple of steps to check if everything is working fine:

1. Check whether you copied sidr css and jquery files at the right places
2. If you are on Chrome, press F12 and click on the Sources tab. On the left hand side you will able to check which CSS and JS files have been loaded
3. If everything has been loaded properly, check whether you are calling sidr before loading jQuery on your page (which I can see you are doing, so no worries)
4. Call sidr with more options like:

$('#simple-menu').sidr({
      name: 'sidr-left',
      side: 'left',
      source: '#sidr'
    });